# Beverage Cooler vs Small Refrigerator for Raw Chicken?

Tags: chicken, refrigerator, raw

I'm entering a bazaar and I currently only have a spare beverage cooler (a Daewoo 123 watt beverage cooler) for my bazaar stall. This being the current circumstance, I want to know if a beverage cooler is cold enough to store raw chicken for at least 8 hours.

Do I have to buy another refrigerator?

Thanks! :D

Comment: Well, how cold does it get?

Answer (score 4):

If you're in the US, you are likely to be inspected. The inspector will use a thermometer to make sure that the chicken is being stored below 40F (4.5C). That is the [FDA requirement](http://www.fda.gov/Food/ResourcesForYou/Consumers/ucm253954.htm) as well. You may or may not need a refrigerator, it sounds to me that first you need a thermometer.

Comment: I totally agree. We looked at purchasing a beverage cooler a few years ago and found that there was a considerable difference in various makes and models. Some will get down to 40 F or below while others don't. (We ended up buying a small refrigerator.) So I would follow @Jolenealaska's advice and check the temperature. I would check it a few times a couple of hours apart to be sure that the temperature remains constant.